# Angular 6, rxjs 6 forkJoin an map

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6

This codesnipped worked as expected in Angular 4:

```
Observable.forkJoin(
  Observable.of('test1'),
  Observable.of('test2')
).map(result => {
  console.log(result);
}).subscribe();
```

This snipped here does not work anymore with rxjs 6:

```
forkJoin(
  of('test1'),
  of('test2')
).pipe(map(result => {
  console.log(result);
})).subscribe();
```

I get the following compile error:

```
ERROR in app/services/bundles/karaf-bundles.service.ts(47,12): error TS2345: Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<[string, string], void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<any, any>'.
  Types of parameters 'source' and 'source' are incompatible.
    Type 'Observable<any>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<[string, string]>'.
      Types of property 'source' are incompatible.
        Type 'import("/Users/moritzvieli/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable").Observable<any>' is not assignable to type 'import("/Users/moritzvieli/repo/cltmgmtconsole/web/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable").Observ...'.
          Types of property 'source' are incompatible.
            Type 'import("/Users/moritzvieli/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable").Observable<any>' is not assignable to type 'import("/Users/moritzvieli/repo/cltmgmtconsole/web/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable").Observ...'.
```

How can i map a forkjoin in Angular 6?

Comment: Use `tap` instead of `map` for logging operations.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out by myself: I imported the wrong forkJoin from "rxjs/observable/forkJoin" instead of "rxjs".

Comment: yes rxjs v6 simplified the namespaces, there are only `rxjs` and `rxjs/operators` now